# Global dependency doesn't work in FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi

```
dependecies.py

from fahttperrors import Fahttperror #this is http exception class (don't worry)
from fastapi import Header

async def headercheck(xxx_access: str = Header(...)):
    
    if xxx_access != 'something':
        return Fahttperror.No_Header

main.py

from fastapi import FastAPI, Query, Depends
from dependencies import headercheck


app = FastAPI(dependencies=[Depends(headercheck)])

@app.get("/item")
async def get_something(x: str):
    return {'x': x,}
```

The problem is I always get back result, if I write input "something" or not. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting as an answer as well. The issue is that your dependency is returning the exception, but to actually stop the request, it needs to be raised. Simply changing `headercheck` to

```py
async def headercheck(xxx_access: str = Header(...)):
    if xxx_access != 'something':
        raise Fahttperror.No_Header
```

should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your example works as it should - but since you didn't include the request you're making in your question, it's hard to say what you expected to happen:

```py
from fastapi.exceptions import HTTPException
from fastapi import FastAPI, Query, Depends, Header

async def headercheck(xxx_access: str = Header(...)):
    if xxx_access != 'something':
        raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail="No no")


app = FastAPI(dependencies=[Depends(headercheck)])

@app.get("/item")
async def get_something(x: str):
    return {'x': x,}
```

If we test it using `curl`, we see that we get the expected behavior. First, without the header:

```bash
$ curl http://localhost:50001/item?x=foo
{"detail":[{"loc":["header","xxx-access"],"msg":"field required","type":"value_error.missing"}]}
```

With the wrong authentication key:

```bash
$ curl -H "XXX-Access: something123" http://localhost:50001/item?x=foo
{"detail":"No no"}
```

And with the correct authentication key:

```bash
$ curl -H "XXX-Access: something" http://localhost:50001/item?x=foo
{"x":"foo"}
```

Comment: And to clarify, the problem in OPs post is that they're `return`ing the exception, they should be `raise`ing it

Comment: @M.O. You should add that a as a separate answer; I didn't notice that at all. That's the actual reason, but I'll leave my answer up.

Comment: Yes it was "raise"